# Android ConstraintLayout constraintHeight_percent not of screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

The XML below says height should be 6% of the height of the entire `ConstraintLayout`, not the parent's view. This particular `ConstraintLayout` is about 2.5 screens high in a `ScrollView`

How can I get the height to be 6% of the screen height?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/udpate_profile"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boardgames"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.06"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="@string/update_profile"
    android:tag="update"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white_color"
    android:background="@color/orange_color"
    android:lines="1"
    />
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you can use horizontal guidelines in constraint layout. For more about guidelines in constraint layout, take a look [here](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html).

Comment: You are right, of course, and I use them plenty. Unfortunately, guidelines have the same issue.  If I set a guideline at 94%, it will be at 94% of the ConstraintLayout, which is about 2.5 screen heights in a ScrollView.  My goal is to have this particular textView be 6% of screenHeight.  Your answer is not on target.

Comment: Can you please put your entire xml code in your question. and also your screenshot is not showing in question. So, make it correct.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I have moved on and that layout had to be substantially reworked to get around the problem.  Bottom line is that 6% of height, or guidelines at some percent, all relate to the height of the Constraint Layout.  In a ScrollView it would be nice if there was someway to refer to the height of the screen or the parent (ScrollView).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may face the same problem, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55226389/5393820), the best way is to use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio`